# How to format data exported to pdf/rtf using displaytag?

Tags: jsp, export, displaytag

How can I format data exported to PDF/RTF using display tag?

My displaytag.properties

```
export.types=csv excel xml pdf rtf
export.excel=true
export.csv=true
export.xml=true
export.pdf=true
export.rtf=true
export.rtf.class=org.displaytag.export.DefaultRtfExportView
export.pdf.class=org.displaytag.export.DefaultPdfExportView
```

I have used caption and footer in display tag.

For showing some colour on different rows I have configured one html decorator. This decorator extends `TableDecorator` and HTML view is working as I expected.

Like this html , how can I create one decorator for PDF??

For this which class I want to extend and which methods I need to write?

I just want to give some colour on rows based on data in that particular row..

Does anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to write a decorator and add it as

```
<display:setProperty name="decorator.media.pdf"  value="org.displaytag.sample.decorators.ItextTotalWrapper" /
```

But you can have your own exporter class.

**For example,**
Create a package `decorators` and create a class `myPdfExportView.java` in this package and copy paste below code in it.

```
package decorators;

import java.awt.Color;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.Rectangle;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;

import javax.servlet.jsp.JspException;

import org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils;
import org.displaytag.Messages;
import org.displaytag.exception.BaseNestableJspTagException;
import org.displaytag.exception.SeverityEnum;
import org.displaytag.export.BinaryExportView;


import com.lowagie.text.Cell;
import org.displaytag.model.Column;
import org.displaytag.model.ColumnIterator;
import org.displaytag.model.HeaderCell;
import org.displaytag.model.Row;
import org.displaytag.model.RowIterator;
import org.displaytag.model.TableModel;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

import com.lowagie.text.BadElementException;
import com.lowagie.text.Chunk;
import com.lowagie.text.Document;

import com.lowagie.text.Element;
import com.lowagie.text.FontFactory;
import com.lowagie.text.HeaderFooter;
import com.lowagie.text.PageSize;
import com.lowagie.text.Phrase;
import com.lowagie.text.Table;


import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;



public class myPdfExportView implements BinaryExportView 
{
private TableModel model;
private boolean exportFull; 
private boolean header;
private boolean decorated;
private Table tablePDF;
private Font smallFont;
private Font headerFont;
public void setParameters(TableModel tableModel, boolean exportFullList, boolean includeHeader,
    boolean decorateValues)
{
    this.model = tableModel;
    this.exportFull = true;
    this.header = includeHeader;
    this.decorated = decorateValues;
}


protected void initTable() throws BadElementException
{
    tablePDF = new Table(this.model.getNumberOfColumns());
    //tablePDF.getDefaultCell().setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
    tablePDF.setCellsFitPage(true);
    tablePDF.setWidth(100);

    tablePDF.setPadding(2);
    tablePDF.setSpacing(0);

    smallFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 7, Font.NORMAL, new Color(0,0,0));
    headerFont = FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 14, Font.BOLD, new Color(192, 20, 25));
}


public String getMimeType()
{
    return "application/pdf"; //$NON-NLS-1$
}


protected void generatePDFTable() throws JspException, BadElementException
{
    if (this.header)
    {
        generateHeaders();
    }
    tablePDF.endHeaders();
    generateRows();
}

public void doExport(OutputStream out) throws JspException
{
    try
    {
        // Initialize the table with the appropriate number of columns
        initTable();

        // Initialize the Document and register it with PdfWriter listener and the OutputStream
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 60, 60, 40, 40);
        document.addCreationDate();

        HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase(this.model.getCaption(), headerFont), false);
        header.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);            
        header.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);   

        HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("Page No - " + document.getPageNumber() , smallFont), true);
        footer.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        footer.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        //footer.setBackgroundColor(new Color(206, 204, 207));


        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, out);

        // Fill the virtual PDF table with the necessary data
        generatePDFTable();
        document.setHeader(header);
        document.setFooter(footer);
        document.open();
        document.add(this.tablePDF);

        document.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new PdfGenerationException(e);
    }
}


protected void generateHeaders() throws BadElementException
{
    Iterator<HeaderCell> iterator = this.model.getHeaderCellList().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        HeaderCell headerCell = iterator.next();

        String columnHeader = headerCell.getTitle();

        if (columnHeader == null)
        {
            columnHeader = StringUtils.capitalize(headerCell.getBeanPropertyName());
        }

        Cell hdrCell = getCell(columnHeader);
        hdrCell.setGrayFill(0.9f);
        hdrCell.setHeader(true);
        tablePDF.addCell(hdrCell);

    }
}


protected void generateRows() throws JspException, BadElementException
{
    // get the correct iterator (full or partial list according to the exportFull field)
    RowIterator rowIterator = this.model.getRowIterator(this.exportFull);
    // iterator on rows
    while (rowIterator.hasNext())
    {
        Row row = rowIterator.next();

        // iterator on columns
        ColumnIterator columnIterator = row.getColumnIterator(this.model.getHeaderCellList());

        while (columnIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Column column = columnIterator.nextColumn();

            // Get the value to be displayed for the column
            Object value = column.getValue(this.decorated);

            Cell cell = getCell(ObjectUtils.toString(value));

            tablePDF.addCell(cell);
        }
    }
    Object value = this.model.getFooter().trim();

    Cell cell = getCell(ObjectUtils.toString(value).replace("\t",""));
    //cell.setBackgroundColor(new Color(206, 204, 207));
    cell.setGrayFill(0.9f);
    cell.setColspan(this.model.getHeaderCellList().size());
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
    cell.setLeading(8);


    tablePDF.addCell(cell);
}


private Cell getCell(String value) throws BadElementException
{
    Cell cell = new Cell(new Chunk(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(value), smallFont));
    cell.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_TOP);
    cell.setLeading(8);
    return cell;
}


static class PdfGenerationException extends BaseNestableJspTagException
{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 899149338534L;


    public PdfGenerationException(Throwable cause)
    {
        super(myPdfExportView.class, Messages.getString("PdfView.errorexporting"), cause); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }


    public SeverityEnum getSeverity()
    {
        return SeverityEnum.ERROR;
    }
}
 }
```

**Note : You can change fonts in above class. You can put colors in this class.**

Make a `displaytag.properties` file in resource folder and add following value

```
  export.pdf.class=decorators.myPdfExportView
```

I hope this example will work for you. But there are even other ways to do this by using `Apache fop`. In this way you need to specify `style sheet` for pdf. But i think it is more complex.

If you want to go with it [Here is the example](https://github.com/mmalmeida/displaytag/blob/master/displaytag/src/main/java/org/displaytag/export/FopExportView.java)